# What would cause the packages/libraries in Spyder to be different from the ones when using pip?

Tags: python, installation, spyder

This problem occurred when I was trying to import pandas:
df = pd.read_html('https://www.macrotrends.net/stocks/charts/BMO/Bank-of-Montreal/dividend-yield-history')

I got the error message:
raise ImportError("lxml not found, please install it")

```
ImportError: lxml not found, please install it
```

So then I pip lxml to install, same error.
then I pip3 lxml, same issue...

And this led me down a rabbit hole of installing and re-installing lxml, pandas, html5lib, html
and then deleting all of Python from my machine as well as Spyder, then re-installing everything and still having the same issue of that error "lxml not found..."

So then I did 'pip list' on command line, lxml and pandas and everything else I installed is there.

I found some code to find all the packages/libraries installed on Spyder using this:
import pkg_resources

```
dists = [str(d).replace(" ","==") for d in pkg_resources.working_set]
for i in dists:
    print(i)
```

And I get:

```
runfile('C:/Users/Preston_Jarvis/untitled0.py', wdir='C:/Users/Preston_Jarvis')
zipp==3.4.1
yapf==0.31.0
wheel==0.36.2
webencodings==0.5.1
wcwidth==0.2.5
And so on...
```

Pandas is there, but lxml or html5lib or hmtl

What could be causing this?

Thank you

Comment: This may sound odd, but my firewall once blocked a download for a python module. Perhaps the same is happening here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How did you install Spyder? Did you use the installer or install it with pip/conda? Where are you installing your packages - what environment?

It appears that the environment where you install packages with pip (e.g. lxml) is different than what Spyder is running with. See https://docs.spyder-ide.org/current/faq.html#using-existing-environment

Note that for Spyder to work with other environments you need to install spyder-kernels in this environment (e.g. `pip install spyder-kernels`)